# How to use assets image in HTML

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I want to use assets bundle in HTML on iOS. For android, I have used `file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/` but don't know how to use it on iOS.

I ampassing the path to `background_image` inside `body` tag of HTML:

```html
<body
   style='
      background-image: url(file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/bgs/bg1.svg);
    '
></body>
```

The above code is working on android but not on iOS.